# Recursively get all HTML between two elements - excluding closing tags - in Javascript/Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, traversal

I need to be able to store certain elements separately in a database, but on retrieval rebuild the HTML for display. Our solution to this (open to suggestions) is to store *leadingHTML* and *trailngHTML* properties of the entry.

This should provide us the ability to be as flexible as we want-- but there's just one catch. I'm banging my head against the wall trying to write the code to parse the HTML. Take the following HTML for example:

```
<h1>this is leadingHTML</h1>
<h2>this is leadingHTML2</h2>
<p class='select' id='1'>A1</p>
<h1 >this is trailngHTML</h1>
<h2>this is trailngHTML2</h2>
<p class='select' id='2'>A2</p>
<h1>this is trailngHTML3</h1>
<h2>this is trailngHTML4</h2>
<p class='select' id='3'>A3</p>
<figure id='fig'>
  <figCaption>
    this is some text
   <span class='select'>B1</span>
     <div>some text <span class='select'>B2</span></div>
</figCaption>
<img class='select' alt='test' src='test.jpg'/>
<img class='select' alt='test' src='test.jpg'/>
<img class='select' alt='test'  src='test.jpg'/>
</figure>
<p class="select">A4</p>
```

It's easy to get all the elements with class "select." But I could really use help getting the string of HTML to go *between* those elements. For the the element `<p class='select' id='3'>A3</p>` , I need a function that can return to me the following string:
values:

*element*

`<p class='select' id='3'>A3</p>`

*leadingHTML*

```
leadingHTML= '<h1>this is trailngHTML3</h1><h2>this is trailngHTML4</h2>'
```

*trailingHTML*

```
trailingHTML= '<figure id='fig><figCaption>this is some text'
```

This way, I can store the elements the way that is required of the project but still reconstruct the HTML for display.

We are using Node.js for a backend, so this will need to be written in Javascript. After lots of frustration, I'm pretty convince there's no way to do this without some ugly code? 
Any help is much appreciated.

So far, this is what I've got (can't say I'm proud):

```
var checkChildren = function walk(node,state,func){
    if (state.isPt===false){
        var state=func(node,state);
    }
    else if(state.isPt===true){
        return state;
    }
    node=$(node).children().first();
    while (node.length>0 && state.isPt!==true){
         state=walk(node,state,func);
         node=$(node).next();
    }
    return state;
};

function getTrailing(start,html){
var checkFind = $(start).find('.pt');
if (checkFind.length>0){
    //selector is in the child somewhere
    state= { html: html, isPt: false}; 
    var getChildHTML = checkChildren(start,state,function(node,state){
        if ($(node).is($(checkFind).first())){
            return { html: html, isPt: true,};  
        } else{
                html=html+'<'+$(node)[0].name;
                for (var key in $(node)[0].attribs){
                        html=html+" "+key+"='"+$(node)[0].attribs[key]+"'";
                };
                html=html+'>';
                return { html: html, isPt: false,};  
        }
    });
        return getChildHTML;
} else{
    return html;
}
}

var start1 = $("#fig");
var html = '';
test=getTrailing(start1,html);
```

and it's returning this:

```
{ html: '<figure id=\'fig\' class=\'test\' style=\'color:red;\'><figcaption class=\'test\' style=\'color:red;\'><span><div>',
  isPt: true }
```

**Update**
To clarify-- the output may be invalid HTML. I simply need string of all the HTML between two elements of interest. If the second element of interest is a descendant, then the result will be invalid HTML (since the string is supposed to stop as soon as it finds the next element).

Comment: SAX to the rescue. Though, your question isn't clear enough.

Comment: Basically-- i need to be start at an element in the DOM, and walk forward collecting all the HTML until I hit the next element of interest. Then, I need to do the same thing going up the DOM. Hope this helps?

@AndreyAtapin as to SAX-- I've never played with it. But I have tried this in PHP using the DOM, as well as Cheerio, jsdom, etc. Assuming SAX provides additional traversal methods?

Comment: if you know how to use it, Cheerio would probably be about the simplest to code.